# Calling a Firebase function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase

I have made this function:

```
  getAllUserLikedProperties(): AngularFirestoreCollection<any> {
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref =>
      ref.where('uid', '==', this._auth.currentUserId)
        .where('likedProp', '==', true)
    );
  }
```

and I have tried to call it liked this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this._property.getAllUserLikedProperties().subscribe(likedProp => {
        console.log(likedProp);
        this.likedProp = likedProp;
      });

    }
```

however it returns this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this._property.getAllUserLikedProperties is not a function
```

Anyone know why? And know how I should call this?

Comment: what is `this._property`?

Comment: What is `_property`?

Comment: @dfsq public _property: PropertyService (linking to a service where I have created that function)

Comment: @sabithpocker I have answered above but could not tag you

Comment: Make sure your service is injectable.

Comment: @dfsq it is injectable

Comment: I’m getting “Property ‘subscribe’ does not exist on type AngularFirestoreCollection<any>”

Comment: @dfsq is that helps at all?

Comment: don't you need to call `valueChanges()` on your collection before you can `subscribe()`

Comment: can you post the constructor of the component along with ngOnInit, or may the complete component file with unwanted functions stripped off? And may be the complete service file as well. The info provided here is not enough to reproduce the problem or even to guess what might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your service function `getAllLikedProperties()` isn't returning an observable, it's returning the value of your filtered afs collection.

Change your function to return an observable, and you can subscribe to it, for example:

```
getAllUserLikedProperties(): AngularFirestoreCollection<any> {

    const properties$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
    properties$.next(this.afs.collection('users', ref =>
      ref.where('uid', '==', this._auth.currentUserId)
        .where('likedProp', '==', true)
    ));
   return properties$;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use RxJs's `of` operator to return the observable stream:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

getAllUserLikedProperties(): AngularFirestoreCollection<any> {
    return of(this.afs.collection('users', ref =>
      ref.where('uid', '==', this._auth.currentUserId)
        .where('likedProp', '==', true)
    ));
}
```

Or, forget the subscription altogether, and just assign the value immediately.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.likedProp = this._property.getAllUserLikedProperties();
}
```